# Agregar automáticamente comillas en un registro TXT

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cuando un usuario ingresa un texto y hace click en el boton enviar,tengo que aregar automáticamente las comillas (si es que no las tiene) en el texto ingresado para que lo guarde sin problema ya que es necesario que las tenga.

Actualmente tengo la validación de si tiene o no comillas para avisarle al usuario que debe agregarlas, pero, como hacer que se agreguen automaticamente?

```
/**
     * Funcion para validar que el contenido del campo Texto en registros TXT empiecen y terminen con "
     * @param text
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    this.validateText = function(text) {
        var pattern = /^\"(.)+\"$/;
        return pattern.test(text);
    };
```

Mi validacion en los inputs: chequear validateText

```
/**
     * Valida los inputs antes de agregar o actualizar un registro.
     * @param inputs
     * @param type
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    this.validateInputs = function(inputs) {
        var valid = true;
        var optionalInputsExceptions = ['txtName'];
        var errors = [];

        //le quito la clase error a todos y luego si tienen errores se le agrega en la validacion siguiente.
        $(inputs).each(function(id, input) {
            $(input).removeClass('error');
        });

        $(inputs).each(function(id, input) {
            if(optionalInputsExceptions.indexOf($(input).attr('name')) == -1) {
                if(!$(input).val()) {
                    $(input).addClass('error');
                    errors.push(i18nHelper.getText('Campo requerido'));
                    valid = false;
                } else {
                    if($(input).attr('name').indexOf('Name') != -1 && !validateName($(input).val())) {
                        $(input).addClass('error');
                        errors.push(i18nHelper.getText('Se ha ingresado un nombre de dominio incorrecto'));
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    if($(input).attr('name').indexOf('Ip') != -1 && !validateIp($(input).val())) {
                        $(input).addClass('error');
                        errors.push(i18nHelper.getText('Se ha ingresado una IP incorrecta'));
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    if($(input).attr('name').indexOf('Text') != -1 && !self.validateText($(input).val())) {
                        $(input).addClass('error');
                        errors.push(i18nHelper.getText('El contenido del registro TXT debe comenzar y terminar con comillas dobles'));
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    if(($(input).attr('name').indexOf('Server') != -1 || $(input).attr('name').indexOf('Domain') != -1) && !self.validateDomain($(input).val())) {
                        $(input).addClass('error');
                        errors.push(i18nHelper.getText('El nombre de '+$(input).data('name')+' es incorrecto'));
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        if(errors.length) {
            if(errors.length > 1) {
                var errorMessage = i18nHelper.getText('Revisa los campos marcados en rojo y completa la información correctamente');
                self.messageManager.showErrorMessage(errorMessage);
            } else {
                self.messageManager.showErrorMessage(errors[0]);
            }
        }

        return valid;
    };
```

y lo unico que tengo en mi boton enviar actualemente:

```
/**
     * Prevengo comportamiento por defecto del boton agregar de cada tipo de registro.
     */
    $('.addMxRecord, .addTxtRecord, .addCnameRecord, .addARecord').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Hola, si tienes una validación para advertir al usuario que debe agregar comillas, entonces no necesitas agregarlas ya que el usuario las debe agregar. Si vas a refactorizar tu código para que se agreguen automáticamente, entonces ya no es necesaria la advertencia al usuario. Solo quería aclarar ese punto. En cuanto a lo que preguntas, veré si puedo responderte pronto. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @MauricioContreras exactamente ya no voy a utilizar la advertencia asi que por ese motivo necesito que se agreguen automaticamente las comillas. Gracias por tu tiempo :)

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo html para replicar el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya tienes una función que devuelve un tipo `boolean` al validar un `string` contra una expresión regular, puedes usar la misma en el evento *clic* del botón `enviar`. Dependiendo del resultado de dicha función agregas (o no) las comillas al valor del elemento `input`.

Veamos un ejemplo sencillo de cómo podrías implementar dicha solución:

```js
// funcion para validar que el texto inicia y finaliza con "
this.validateText = function(text) {
  const pattern = /^\"(.)+\"$/;
  return pattern.test(text);
};

$('.addFirst, .addSecond').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // <- se previene el comportamiento por defecto del botón
  let text = ''; // establece la variable text a string nulo o vacío
  // verificamos qué botón fue presionado
  switch($(this).attr('id')) {
    case 'addFirst':
      text = $('#first').val();
      if(!text) return; // si el input está vacío salimos
      if(!validateText(text)) {  // si el input no posee comillas dobles al inicio y al final, se las agregamos
        text = '"' + text + '"';
      }
      $('#first').val(text); // asignamos al input el resultado de la validación
      break;
    case 'addSecond':
      text = $('#second').val();
      if(!text) return;
      if(!validateText(text)) {
        text = '"' + text + '"';
      }
      $('#second').val(text);
      break;
    default:
      return;
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <div class="box">
    <label for="first">Primero</label><br>
    <input id="first" type=text>
    <button id="addFirst" class="addFirst" type="button">Agregar Primero</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  <label for="second">Segundo</label><br>
  <input id="second" type=text>
  <button id="addSecond" class="addSecond" type="button">Agregar Segundo</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

**NOTA:**

Ahora, hay un detalle al realizar la validación de esta forma, ya que la expresión regular definida permite que el `String` contenga cualquier carácter excepto salto de línea. Por lo tanto, el carácter `"` es válido. Así, los siguientes valores darán un resultado que tal vez no sea el deseado:

> - `"` produce ==> `"""`
> - `"text` produce ==> `""text"`
> - `txt"` produce ==> `"txt""`
> - `txt"text"txt` produce ==> `"txt"text"txt"`

Una forma de resolverlo sería usando un [`negative look ahead`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html), pero lamentablemente el motor de RegEx de JS de la mayoría de navegadores aún [no soporta](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind) la característica `look around`.

Esto implica realizar una validación un poco más exhaustiva para los casos antes mencionados y algún otro caso que se me escape por ahora.